# Implementing passport-http-bearer token with sails.js

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js, passport.js, http-token-authentication

I am trying to implement passport's `passport-http-bearer` strategy, but it found no user with info `Bearer realm="Users"`.

My `request` is a post request:

```
{'token':'simple_access_token',}
```

Any one has any idea why this error occurs? Also I know here `req` should be `https` or `ssl` instead of `http`. How do I do that?

The code I am using is:

```
bearerPassportToken: function(req,res){
        passport.authenticate('bearer', function(err, user, info){
          if ((err) || (!user)) {
            if (err) return;
            if (!user)  
                console.log("info");//Info: Bearer realm="Users"
            res.redirect('/login');
            return;
          }
          req.logIn(user, function(err){
            if (err){
                res.redirect('/login');
            }
            //Need to write code for redirection
            ;
          });
        })(req, res);
    },
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

We had to implement securing the Sails-based API with bearer tokens recently, and here's what we did (tested with `0.9.x`):

1) Connect passport as a custom middleware in `config/passport.js` (or it can be `config/express.js`, depending on your taste):

```
/**
 * Passport configuration
 */
var passport = require('passport');

module.exports.express = {
  customMiddleware: function(app)
  {
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());
  }
};
```

2) Secure necessary controllers/actions with a policy in `config/policies.js`:

```
module.exports.policies = {
  // Default policy for all controllers and actions
  '*': 'authenticated'
};
```

3) Create the policy that checks the bearer in `api/policies/authenticated.js`:

```
/**
 * Allow any authenticated user.
 */
var passport = require('passport');

module.exports = function (req, res, done) {
  passport.authenticate('bearer', {session: false}, function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) return done(err);
    if (user) return done();

    return res.send(403, {message: "You are not permitted to perform this action."});
  })(req, res);
};
```

4) Define the bearer strategy for passport in `services/passport.js` (or wherever else you find it more appropriate for your specific application):

```
var passport = require('passport'),
  BearerStrategy = require('passport-http-bearer').Strategy;

/**
 * BearerStrategy
 *
 * This strategy is used to authenticate either users or clients based on an access token
 * (aka a bearer token).  If a user, they must have previously authorized a client
 * application, which is issued an access token to make requests on behalf of
 * the authorizing user.
 */
passport.use('bearer', new BearerStrategy(
  function(accessToken, done) {
    Tokens.findOne({token: accessToken}, function(err, token) {
      if (err) return done(err);
      if (!token) return done(null, false);
      if (token.userId != null) {
        Users.find(token.userId, function(err, user) {
          if (err) return done(err);
          if (!user) return done(null, false);
          // to keep this example simple, restricted scopes are not implemented,
          // and this is just for illustrative purposes
          var info = { scope: '*' }
          done(null, user, info);
        });
      }
      else {
        //The request came from a client only since userId is null
        //therefore the client is passed back instead of a user
        Clients.find({clientId: token.clientId}, function(err, client) {
          if (err) return done(err);
          if (!client) return done(null, false);
          // to keep this example simple, restricted scopes are not implemented,
          // and this is just for illustrative purposes
          var info = { scope: '*' }
          done(null, client, info);
        });
      }
    });
  }
));
```

This way you'll be able to access the API by having your bearer in the `Authorization` header: `Bearer 8j4s36...`.

In this example a separate server was used to request/issue tokens, but you might as well do it within the same app (then you'll have to apply the policy to selected controllers only).

Comment: Thank you very much

Any idea what last (req res) parameters are after passport.authenticate?

Comment: @VampireCoder Those are current request/response. It's like `passport.authenticate` is a function returning a function which is being called with `(req, res)`.

Comment: When I define ```passport.use('bearer', new BearerStrategy...``` the ```function(accessToken, done)``` is never triggered.. Any idea why?

Comment: @CarlosRicardo Check if the policy is in place, in `config/policies.js`, as well as in `api/policies/authenticated.js`.

Comment: @bredikhin, sorry, the Bearer Authoorization header was not correct, missed the "Beared" before token :D thanks anyway

Comment: @CarlosRicardo No prob.

Comment: passport.session() is unnecessary since you're not using sessions when using the Bearer (token) strategy.

Comment: @bredikhin I am following the above instructions but my requests are timing out as I never hit some of the callbacks. Putting logs throughout, I see that I am getting into policy evaluation in `authenticated.js`, but the `function(token, cb)` callback in `services/passport.js` is never triggered. I've double checked that I'm spelling "Bearer" correctly in the request and that my app is using the middleware that initializes passport. Any ideas what may be going wrong? I'm using Sails `0.11.2`, passport `0.3.0`, and passport-http-bearer `1.0.2`.

Comment: @bredikhin the basic idea for me was to send Authorization header with Bearer prefix word!